# SQL Query Not Writing File

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-data-studio

I am running the following query in IBM data studio but it does not write the file to my library, it errors out without a description of the error. Can anyone help, is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DANBLIB/FILE1;
CREATE TABLE DANBLIB/FILE1 AS
(
SELECT HHIITMN AS "Product Number", SUBSTR(HHIDTES,5,2) || 
SUBSTR(HHIDTES,7,2) || SUBSTR(HHIDTES,1,4) AS "Transaction Date"
       
FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.HHIORDDP --Order Detail History

WHERE HHICMPN = '  1' 
      
ORDER BY HHIDTES
) WITH DATA;
```

Comment: Have you tried sql naming instead of the system one? That is: `DANBLIB.FILE1` instead of `DANBLIB/FILE1`.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I did, I tried it both ways with the same result.

Comment: It's strange enough, that it doesn't return any error description. Have you tried some other jdbc client like dbeaver?

Comment: I have not but I can, I just don't know why it will not work with IBM data studio.